# How to sum a column on condition if value is in another list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum a column based on if the unique identifier is within another list I have defined. (The list is a subset of all of the unique identifiers). So I am trying to do it like this:

```
sum = data.loc[data['unique_identifier'] in somelist, 'number'].sum()
```

But I get back a TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. I know that this works below:

```
sum = data.loc[data['unique_identifier'] > 100, 'number'].sum()
```

Any ideas would be helpful and let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Comment: Try `sum = data.loc[data['unique_identifier'].isin(somelist), 'number'].sum()`

Comment: Yup - I knew it wasn't something too crazy just couldn't find it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `.isin(values)`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html

```
sum = data.loc[data['unique_identifier'].isin(somelist), 'number'].sum()
```